# Commuting generators of different Lie Algebras

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose that I have two different Lie algebras $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ with generators $M_{i}$ and $N_{j}$.

1. Is it always the case that, the commutator (which is assumed to exist throughout this question), $[M_{i},N_{j}] \equiv M_{i} N_{j} - N_{j} M_{i} =0 ~ \forall ~ i,j$ ?
2. If not, what are the implications of the commutator being zero? Can we say that one of $\mathfrak{a}$ or $\mathfrak{b}$ is a normal subgroup of a cover and the other is a quotient subgroup? Any other implications? Can we make some statement about diagonalization of a linear combination of elements of $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$?

More particularly, I have generators of $\mathfrak{su(2)}$ as $J_{0,\pm}$ which all commute with a generator of $u(1)$, $J_{3}$. I'm trying to understand the implications of such an event specially since we have $\mathfrak{su(2)} \times \mathfrak{u(1)} \simeq \mathfrak{u(2)}$. As a physics student, I have used typical conventions from physics - kindly let me know if any clarification is required.

Thanks!

Edit : clarification regarding the Lie bracket & commutators

Comment: The Lie bracktet $[M_i,N_j]$ is not defined. Are you considering the direct product $\mathfrak{a}\times \mathfrak{b}$ with the natural Lie bracket? Then $[M_i,N_j]$ is defined and trivially zero.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the bracket I'm considering is a commutator. Modifying to reflect the same.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{a}$ is a Lie algebra not consisting of matrices, a "commutator" is not defined. Even a product $M_iN_j$ is not defined between two vectors $M_i$ and $N_j$. Recall that the elements of a Lie algebra are vectors.

Comment: @DietrichBurde edited, the commutator is assumed to exist and the algebras definitely consist of matrices

Comment: Then you should edit your text and say that $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ are both subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$. The answer still is, that these Lie brackets may not vanish. Consider a non-trivial semidirect product $\mathfrak{a}\ltimes \mathfrak{b}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde They may not vanish in general (which is what point 1 above is asking) but they definitely do vanish in particular cases. See the example in the text.

Comment: Yes, I said "may not vanish". If they all do vanish, this just says that $\mathfrak{a}\times \mathfrak{b}$ is the direct product.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two different Lie algebras, it does not necessarily make sense to take commutators between elements from them. If your Lie algebras are both sub Lie algebras of the same Lie algebra, then sure, you can do it, but it will rarely be the case that elements commute. As a simple example, take $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

In your case, both your Lie algebras are Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, and since $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ commutes with all of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, its generator will too. Remember that $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ is just the non-zero complex numbers, so it makes sense that they commute with all matrices.